# Apache httpd module that behaves like mod_ldap?

Tags: authentication

I'd like to authenticate and authorize users with Salesforce rather than LDAP/AD. Is there a module out there that will do this?

The web services secured by LDAP are not browser facing and use HTTP Basic authentication in SSL and cannot change easily so OAuth is not useful here I think.

Not finding it out there if it exists.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's an Apache module available for it but you should look at [this](http://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api_streaming/Content/code_sample_auth_oauth.htm) tutorial for how to setup auth for your apps using Salesforce oAuth 2.0

From a broader perspective, you should also look into [Salesforce Identity Mangement](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Identity) Salesforce can server as a SP as well as iDP, its supports oAuth2 for auth dance and RESTful web services. Instead of trying to replace LDAP, you can also implement a SSO between your LDAP server and Salesforce identity.